# modelling minimal threshold line

Tags: regression, threshold, extreme-value

I am examining the relationship between population density and incidence of a disease (calculate by count of number of cases / population) in a geographical area sub-divided into adjoining districts.

When I plot population density against log10 of disease incidence, I get the following:

[image]
I want to test the hypothesis that there is a minimum relationship between population density and incidence. That is to say, for a given population density, disease incidence will (always) be above a certain threshold (line drawn manually on the plot) and that the bottom, right section of the plot will always be empty (or, if not, something special is going on that needs scrutiny)

My question is, what techniques and tools should I be looking at to formalise this hypothesis? How would I statistically derive this minimum line?

Incidentally, I work in R so would appreciate it if someone could point me to specific documentation/packages)

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal as stated is a bit unrealistic: estimating when "disease incidence will (**always**) be above a certain threshold" is not something stats or probability can solve. However, we can estimate thresholds above which different proportions of the data will fall, and how this changes with population density. The methods below can help you quantify this.

To begin with, I would try quantile regression. While a regular regression attempts to find a line that (very loosely speaking) passes through the middle of all the points, a quantile regression allows you to choose any quantile you are interested in. For e.g., in your case you can attempt to fit a line for the 5th percentile (in other words, a line that passes above only 5% of the data). The package `quantreg` allows you to do this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/index.html

I would add a couple of cautions: 1) Quantile regression is data hungry, and the more extreme the quantile you are interested in, the more data you will need to bound your parameters tightly. So think carefully about uncertainty estimation and the quantity of data you have. 2) Even if a straight line works well for the mean (which is not necessary), it may not for the extreme quantiles. In these cases, there are analagous methods that can deal with this (quantile LOESS and GAMLSS). Quantile LOESS: LOESS as quantile regression:regression. GAMLSS is a newer and very useful method, but I know less about it so cannot describe its limitations well.